# Missing random custom events in Parse Explorer

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using Parse to track custom events. This is the code for tracking the events:

```
NSLog(event)    
PFAnalytics.trackEventInBackground(eventName, dimensions: dimensions, block: { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (nil != error) {
        NSLog(succeeded.description + "\t" + error!.description)
    }
    else {
        NSLog(succeeded.description)
    }
})
```

I keep getting `true` statements in my console but when I check Parse Explorer and list all custom events ordered by timestamp it becomes apparent that many events (sometimes more than 50%) are missing compared to the log statements.

They don't seem to show up even after hours of waiting. Am I doing something wrong? I assume `succeeded` would become `false` if I exceeded my quota (which I certainly don't do as it is my only app and still in development) or if a event was dropped for any reason.